# Neptune 3 Pro, Prusa slicer won't stick on plate

Tags: printing

I have a big problem with my printer Neptune 3 Pro. I used Cura, Orca slicer and Prusa slicer and the result are the same. I can't figuring out how can fix the problem. When I print the PLA I got the result like on image. The PLA won't stick on the plate. I clean the plate many times, I calibrate the Z hight. Can you please help me. I don't know what is the problem.

Image: [image]

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: fyi this is off-topic here, as it's unrelated to programming and is very specifically related to your 3d printer, tuning, etc. Probably best to reach out to  a 3D-printing community forum, such as the ones on reddit. Also: please be mindful of tags - neither [tag:neptune] nor [tag:3d] have anything to do with 3D printing - I removed both of these, accordingly.